# MySQL como guardar uma lista de IDs em uma coluna?

Tags: mysql

Como guardo uma lista em uma coluna no MySQL? Quero dizer, que tipo de variável do MySQL devo usar?

Tenho uma tabela em um banco MySQL onde guardo algumas informações de um produto (tamanho, cód, etc.).
Uma dessas informações são as notas de compra desse produto. Uma vez que o produto é reposto no estoque, haverá várias notas para um mesmo produto, que eu precisarei listar mais tarde. Eu tenho uma tabela de "Notas" e uma de "Produto".

Gostaria que na coluna "notas" da tabela "Produto" eu pudesse guardar uma lista de IDs da tabela "Notas".

Comment: Campos multivalorados não são um boa ideia .

Comment: Acho que está complicado um pouco à toa. Seria muito mais simples uma tabela de relacionamento à parte, ou simplesmente um campo a mais nos ítens das notas pra indicar quais foram consumidos e quais não. Tem muitas soluções para o problema que você está mencionando, mas essa sua parece mais complicada do que todas que eu já vi (o que não impede a sua solução de ser boa pro seu caso individual, afinal, sem ver o resto do sistema, não dá pra saber de fato). Até separar o estoque por notas individuais é mais fácil que isso (as entradas no estoque corresponderem às notas, com campo de "consumo").

Comment: Oi @Bacco. Eu tentei simplificar o que eu queria dizer, mas lendo agora, acho que compliquei pra vocês. As notas que eu me refiro, na verdade, são PIs(Proforma Invoice). Às vezes eu preciso saber em quais proformas foi comprado um certo item, por isso preciso tê-los relacionados de alguma forma. Se foi consumido ou não... não me interessa, entendeu? Eu não estou sabendo relacionar e vou dar uma pesquisada no que vocês sugeriram (eu não sou programador, estou precisando aprender na marra). Muito obrigado, cara! Abs

Comment: @Dtag pense nessa tabela separada. É quase a mesma coisa que vc disse, mas nao vai gravar junto dos outros dados. Vai ter o id do produto, id da nota de entrada, e se precisar uma outra relação com as notas de saida.

Comment: @Bacco é, vou tentar isso. Obrigadão!